# Delete nth field of specific line using awk

Tags: bash, text, replace, awk, field

I am having trouble figuring out how to delete the nth field of a specific line in my awk script.  Basically i have 4 fields, and I'm merging the second and 3rd fields into one, setting the 3rd fields equal to the fourth field, and now i need to eliminate the 4th field.

it looks like this:

```
$2=$2" "$3
$3=$4
$4=""
```

this doesn't work as even though $4 is now an empty string their is still a trailing tab about $3 and I believe also $4.  I need a way to cut this one specific line down to just the first 3 fields but I haven't been able to figure out how. Any help?

Input lines looks like this:

```
string1 [tab] string2 [tab] string3 [tab] string4
```

and I'm trying to make the output lines look like this:

```
string1 [tab] string2 string3 [tab] string4]
```

This is within a conditional so ***I need it to operate on the current individual line and not every line in the file***.

For example let's say I have the following input file:

```
12345    jones, michael    madison    0101-10101-2
12345    water    oil    0101-10101-2
12346    jones, mike    mason    0101-10101-3
12347    jones, nick    norris    0101-10101-4
```

and I want to leave the 2nd line above as-is since the 3rd field is `oil` but combine the 2nd and 3rd fields otherwise then my expected output would be:

```
12345    jones, michael madison    0101-10101-2
12345    water    oil    0101-10101-2
12346    jones, mike mason    0101-10101-3
12347    jones, nick norris    0101-10101-4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$3!="oil"{$0 = $1 FS $2 " " $3 FS $4} 1' file     
12345   jones, michael madison  0101-10101-2
12345   water   oil     0101-10101-2
12346   jones, mike mason       0101-10101-3
12347   jones, nick norris      0101-10101-4
```

Comment: wouldn't this perform that combining operation on every line in the file?